# Adobe Reader Security

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

We set up new domains to forward to an application on our jboss platform.  These new domains are used in the links on a pdf created with itext.  They are shorter links to additional data, as we wanted to hide the full links.  These links forward to our application correctly.  The problem is that, when a link is clicked, adobe displays a dialog box (printed below) asking if the user wants to allow this connection.  Unfortunately, every time the user clicks a link in the pdf, he will get the dialog box below.  I read in the Adobe documentation that cross-domain access triggers a security warning.  Have any of you encountered and solved this problem? Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

[image: PDF Link Dialog box]

Comment: Your question is misleading, it's not about iText but about Adobe Reader. Have you tried this? https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1418097

Comment: If that link works for you, then I will post it as an answer with full details so you can accept it. When I am at a pc (using the Android app now l

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: I would suggest to no bother with writing up a full answer, because this question is not only unrelated to iText but also not about a practical, programming related problem.

Comment: @RadLexus how about I copy/paste an answer *and then* flag the question as off topic?

Comment: @Amedee: yes, you can do that - but would it not indicate that it's okay to ask *any* question on Stack Overflow "as long as I get an answer"? I mean, I have a few tax related questions as well...

Comment: Go ahead, if it is about programming tax software

Answer (score 0):

[Per Adobe](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1418097):

Allow or block links to the Internet in PDFs

Clicking any link to the Internet poses a potential security risk. Malicious websites can transfer harmful content or silently gather data. If you are concerned about these risks, you can configure Acrobat and Reader to display a warning when a PDF attempts to connect to an Internet site.

You can allow Acrobat and Reader to contact selected websites by adding their addresses (URLs) to your list of trusted websites in the Trust Manager preferences. Alternatively, you can allow all URLs.

Note: If the options in the Manage Internet Access dialog box are disabled, select Custom Setting. If options are still disabled, your product could be under an administrator’s control with those restrictions in place.

1. Choose Edit > Preferences (Windows) or Acrobat/Adobe Reader > Preferences (Mac OS).
2. From the Categories on the left, select Trust Manager.
3. Click Change Settings to specify the default behavior for accessing the Internet from PDFs.
4. Choose from the following options:

   - To allow access to all URLs, select Allow PDF Files To Access All Web Sites.
   - To restrict access to all URLs, select Block PDF Files’ Access To All Web Sites.
   - To restrict access to only the URLs you specify, select Custom Setting.
   - To add a website, type its URL in the Host Name text box and click Allow or Block.
   - To remove a URL you no longer want to visit, select the website in the list and click Delete.
   - To specify what the program should do with websites not in your custom list, select one of these options: Always Ask, Allow Access, Block Access.

For more information, see the Application Security Guide at http://www.adobe.com/go/learn_acr_appsecurity_en.

Note: If you open a protected PDF and receive a prompt to allow or block a URL, select Remember My Action For This Site. This reply adds the URL to this list.